# How to use php fo get image src only

Tags: php

I've a function get_image_html().
The function output is:

```
<img src="http://example.com/my-image.jpg" alt="My Image Alt">
```

How to strip all tags to get image url only ?

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect 
questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we 
will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us 
[what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. 
This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use preg_match function to get elements attribute

```
$string = '<img src="http://example.com/my-image.jpg" alt="My Image Alt">';
$matches = array();
preg_match( '/src="([^"]*)"/i', $string, $matches ) ;
print_r( $matches[1] ) ;
```